# delegated event on form in every table row changes only the first one

Tags: jquery, forms

I have the following delegated event installed on a checkbox inside a form that is present in every row of a table:

```
jQuery(function() {
  var isChecked;
  $('#order-statuses-onweek tbody').on('change', 'form #order_status_p', function(event) {
    return $(this).parents('form').find('#order_status_s').attr('disabled', isChecked($(this))).toggleClass('disabled');
  });
  isChecked = function(el) {
    return $(el).prop('checked');
  };
```

My problem is that no matter which row I click a checkbox it is the first row that is changing only.

Actual code of a sample row with the form:

```
<td>
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/order_statuses/776" class="form-inline" data-remote="true" id="edit_order_status_776" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch" /></div>
    <label class="checkbox" for="order_status_s">
      <input name="order_status[s]" type="hidden" value="0" />
      <input id="order_status_s" name="order_status[s]" type="checkbox" value="1" />Wózek
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox" for="order_status_p">
      <input name="order_status[p]" type="hidden" value="0" />
      <input id="order_status_p" name="order_status[p]" type="checkbox" value="1" />Produkcja
    </label>
  </form>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID has to be unique. That's why it is called ID.
Calling methods for specific `$('#id')` will only apply to the first occurring element matching the id, whilst using classes, `$('.class')`, will apply to all elements matching the class.

If you want to share characteristics, events or other stuff with elements, you should always use classes.

In your example, simply change

```
<input id="order_status_s" name="order_status[s]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

to

```
<input class="order_status_s" name="order_status[s]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

and do the same for `order_status_p`.

Then, in your javascript/jQuery code, change `#` to `.`:

```
$('#order-statuses-onweek tbody').on('change', 'form .order_status_p', function(event) {
    return $(this).parents('form').find('.order_status_s').attr('disabled', isChecked($(this))).toggleClass('disabled');
    });
```

Comment: I was aware that in proper HTML document IDs can only be unique, but I didn't expect to have such issue with event propagation. I expected that even if IDs will not be unique, jQuery will be able to properly traverse the DOM tree starting with checkbox (target). But somehow it always took first checkbox with given ID, just like you explained.

Comment: I also added a class common for all checkboxes that trigger the event, so event code to install the delegated event is now `$('#order-statuses-onweek tbody').on('change', 'form .order_status_p', function(event) { ... });`